# What is the meaning of "Two layers of bad smell"?

Tags: meaning

In opening scene of Comedy movie *Dinner for Schmucks (2010)*, Tim saw Barry rubbing Barry's face with aftershave.

> Tim: Why are you putting on aftershave?
>
> Barry: Oh, force of habit. When I was married,  I used to stay up late
>   working on my mice, and Martha hated the smell of formaldehyde.
>
> Tim: You can smell them both, Barry. **Two layers of bad smell**.
>
> Barry: That's exactly what Martha used to say.

Answer (score 2):

**Two layers of bad smell** refers to the smell of formaldehyde and the smell of aftershave.

When Barry was married, he used to stay up late to work on his mice which involved using formaldehyde. Because his wife hated the smell of formaldehyde, he would try to eliminate/reduce the smell by putting on some aftershave. Tim, in this conversation, is telling Barry that his wife could smell the two layers of bad smell: both the formaldehyde and the aftershave. Barry wasn't actually making things better by putting on the aftershave and in fact, he was making things worse by layering one bad smell (aftershave) on top of the other (formaldehyde).

Comment: It could also be a mean joke, in a different context without the formaldehyde, if Tim meant to imply that Barry's *natural* odor is already bad, and the aftershave only adds another layer on top.